# What is the Chinese term for "architrave"?

Tags: terminology

When you put a door frame (or window frame) in a wall there is an ugly gap between the door frame and the wall along the top and on both sides.

Normally, we use strips of thin, moulded wood to cover this gap. In English we call those strips of wood "architrave". I believe the Americans call that "door casing".

What is that called in Chinese?

I came up with 门套管、 阑头、门（边）缘 but I am not very happy.

Any carpenters out there? 这儿有木工吗？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for architrave, it’s “楣樑” (門框上方橫接的承重小樑).

> strips of thin, moulded wood to cover this gap

try “門框飾邊“, “門框飾板” or “門框飾條“

have fun :)